# Selenium response differs from browser view

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, caching

I am try to use Selenium with python. 
Here is my snippet

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--incognito')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
element = driver.switch_to_active_element()

element.send_keys('Donald Trump')
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Here is two screenshot both made in incognito mode.

Left one is controlled by selenium.

And to see right one i just copy the link from left and paste it to incognito chrome window.

[image: Difference]

Not hard to see that both windows are in incognito mode, but results are different.
any idea why this can be possible?
Mb i mess smthng?
I am stuck with this.
Looking for somebody help.

Answer (score 1):

Google has an artificial intelligence to categorize what would be most relevant to each user. For the selenium private browser, these are the most important things chosen by google. For your personal browser are other choices.

Themes such as politics, soccer team or fashion will change according to the user because everyone likes to see certain subjects, but probably themes like periodic table will not change because all users follow practically the same search flow.

Think that just having information like plugins in incognito already influences your search. Remember that you may be browsing anonymously, but you are still using the google browser, which knows a great deal about your computer and browsing choices.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in snapshots says it all.

- In the first snapshot the one generated by *Selenium* is a result of the *Purified Search Results*. In my case it is as follows :

[image: google_search_selenium]

- In the second snapshot the one you observe is a result of the *Manipulated Search Results* which is produced after passing through several filters (*e.g. Ad Blocker and 3 others*) as follows :

[image: Ad Blocker and 3 others]

- In my case here is the search result snapshot which is pretty much similar as follows :

[image: google_search_user]

### Conclusion

When *Google Search* is conducted under the influence of *Web Extensions* and *other environmental conditions* search results may vary as per the prevailing conditions.